# ASP.net get form values from postback inline vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

This codes works great except for getting the post values...  I have the select hard coded now, but I want to obtain the values from the form post and populate from that...  I hope there's a way to do this using inline asp.net (vb.net)...

```
<%@ Page language="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>ListView Templates Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

      <h3>Modifying Quantities for: </h3>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sql" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [name],[id] FROM [markets]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="yearSQLDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT distinct(year) as year from transactions order by year asc">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT shortname, id from products order by name asc">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:Label ID="market" runat="server" Text="Market:" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="markets" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="Sql" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" >
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Products:" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="products" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="shortname" DataValueField="id" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <!--TODO use databind in Page_Load to fill from SQL and then use distributor ID instead of name to match-->

    <asp:Label ID="year" runat="server" Text="Year:" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="years" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="yearSQLDataSource" DataTextField="year" DataValueField="year" >
    </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" text="Submit" postbackurl="fourrosesformDataList3.aspx" />


      <asp:ListView ID="ContactsListView" 
        DataSourceID="ContactsDataSource" 
         DataKeyNames="id"
        runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
          <table cellpadding="2" width="640px" border="1" runat="server" id="tblProducts">
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
              <th id="Th1" runat="server">Action</th>
              <th id="Th2" runat="server">Month</th>
              <th id="Th3" runat="server">Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
          </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
            <td>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="Server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("MonthName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:Label DataTextField = "standardcase" ID="standardcase" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("standardcase") %>' />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
          <tr style="background-color: #ADD8E6">
            <td>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />&nbsp;
              <asp:LinkButton ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </td>
             <td>
              <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("MonthName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="standardcase" DataTextField = "standardcase" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("standardcase") %>' 
                MaxLength="50" /><br />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>

      <!-- This example uses Microsoft SQL Server and connects      -->
      <!-- to the AdventureWorks sample database. Use an ASP.NET    -->
      <!-- expression to retrieve the connection string value       -->
      <!-- from the Web.config file.                                -->
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ContactsDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT standardcase, shortname, datename(month,dateadd(month, t.month - 1, 0)) as MonthName, t.id as id
         from transactions t, products p where p.id=t.product_id and year = 2009 and market_id = 1 and product_id = 1"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE transactions
                       SET standardcase = @standardcase
                       WHERE id = @id"
                       >
      </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

so instead of "where p.id=t.product_id and year = 2009 and market_id = 1 and product_id = 1"

I want to do "where p.id=t.product_id and year = @postYear and market_id = @postMarket and product_id = @postProduct" from the form at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selectparameters tag of asp:sqldatasource.  Exactly how you do it depends on whether you are getting the value from a control on the current page.

```
 <asp:sqldatasource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
      selectcommand="SELECT standardcase, shortname, datename(month,dateadd(month, t.month - 1, 0)) as MonthName, t.id as id
     from transactions t, products p where p.id=t.product_id and year =  @year and market_id = @market and product_id = @product">
      <selectparameters>
          <asp:controlparameter name="year" controlid="DropDownList1" propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
          <asp:controlparameter name="market" controlid="DropDownList1" propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
          <asp:controlparameter name="products" controlid="DropDownList1" propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
      </selectparameters>
  </asp:sqldatasource>
```

Be aware that this does leave a vulnerability, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The formparamter property worked for me:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formparameter.formfield(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formparameter.formfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I may look at the controlparameter too...  T

Comment: Yeah, if FormParameter is the right one for you, you can add the code here and accept your own answer (you may have to wait 2 days).